# Travelling to UK after overstaying visa

Tags: united-kingdom

My wife and I are planning to go to UK. I am an EU citizen and she is Malaysian. She has overstayed her 6-month visa, but she left the UK voluntarily, at her own expense, a year ago. Can we return to the UK now? We have our marriage certificate and all the documents, and we want to settle there. We just don’t want to have any issues on the border. Has anyone been in this situation so far?

Comment: Questions about selling in another country belong on [Expatriates.SE], but in short as long as you go before the end of the year,you should be fine.

Comment: How long did she overstay?  How many days?

Comment: About 2 years..